# Java LinkedList: How to insert things to a specific index?

Tags: java, linked-list

I had a computer lab last week and didn't get full credit since I used ArrayLists and an Array to accomplish finding which index to put something in, and inserted the TargetValue there. Can someone show me the proper way to do this with LinkedLists only?

CODE:

1. It generates a random list of 30 integers.
2. It displays the list of 30 integers backwards.
3. It generates a random number that will be out "TargetValue".
4. Sorts the LinkedList from smallest -> largest.
5. NEEDED: I'd like to see the proper way to insert something into its index at a specific point.

---

```
public class LAB11 {
    public static LinkedList<Integer> LabList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    public static ArrayList<Integer> LabArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public static LinkedList<Integer> SortedList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    public static int TargetValue;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        PopulateList();
        BackwardsList();
        GenerateTarget();
        SortList();
    }

    public static void PopulateList(){
        Random random = new Random();
        int range = 100 - 1 + 1;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 30 ; i++){
            int rn = random.nextInt(range) + 1;
            LabList.add(rn);
            LabArray.add(rn);
        }
        System.out.println("LINKED LIST GENERATED\n" + LabList);
    }

    public static void BackwardsList(){
        LabList.clear();
        for(int i = 29 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
            int temp = LabArray.get(i);
            LabList.add(temp);
        }
        System.out.println("\nLINKED LIST REVERSED\n" + LabList);
    }

    public static void GenerateTarget(){
        Random random = new Random();
        int range = 100 - 1 + 1;
        TargetValue = random.nextInt(range) + 1;
        System.out.println("\nTARGET VALUE: " + TargetValue);
    }

    public static void SortList(){
        Collections.sort(LabList);
        System.out.println(LabList);

        // NEEDED: INSERT TAGETVALUE INTO THE INDEX THAT KEEPS NUMBERS IN ORDER STILL.
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the code in the post instead of linking to it.

Comment: [Collections.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) will help with the sorting. And [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-) for inserting into a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

A traditional `LinkedList` data structure does not support `O(1)` insertion to a specified index. The defining structure of a `LinkedList` is that each element holds a pointer to its next neighbor.

Let's look at a simple implementation:

```
public class Node {
  int x;
  Node next;

  public Node(int x)
  {
     this.x = x;
  }
}
```

We can then create a `LinkedList` like so:

```
Node n1 = new Node(3);
n1.next = new Node(4);
n1.next.next = new Node(1);
n1.next.next.next = new Node(0);

3 --> 4 --> 1 --> 0
```

Notice that the only object immediately available to us in `n1`. To reach the others, we need to traverse the `LinkedList`. The same logic applies for insertion to a specified index. We must traverse the structure to arrive at a point where we can perform the insert.

This pseudocode shows how it can be done

```
Node current = n1
Node insertionNode = new Node(10);
int insertionInx = 2
int currentIdx = 0
while currentIdx < insertionIdx - 1
  current = current.next
  currentIdx++
temp = current.next
current.next = insertionNode
current.next.next = temp
```

Of course you will have to handle edge cases like the insertion index exceeding the length of the list, but this should help you understand the data structure better.